# Google FooBar challenge showing Blacklisted_Code error

Tags: java

I stumbled upon the Google Foo Bar challenge today. While solving the first question which was pretty simple --> Involved creating concatenation of all prime numbers in String, let's call it as `primeString`, and then just taking 5 lettered substring from that `primeString` from given index i.

I was happy that it was easy and tried approach of generating prime numbers using Sieve. It showed the error shown in the image below. I also tried normal brute force method of generating prime numbers, again it showed the same error.

I am using Java language to solve it. I am using an online Java compiler as IDE and then I copy-pasted my code into the editor since the default editor does not have any code compilation feature.

I searched throughout the meaning of this error. I couldn't find any solution. Can someone please explain to me what this error is?

[image: verify Solution.java error]

Comment: I would assume it is because your approach is "blacklisted". That is another way of saying: "Forbidden", "Not allowed", "Disqualified". Without seeing the full text of the rules I can only speculate. But I would suggest trying a different approach.

Comment: I just mapped the same Java code to python, I am not getting BLACKLISTED_CODE error. I wonder what's the issue with Java.

Comment: Did you write the Java code for the sieve yourself, or did you find it online?

Comment: I wrote the code from scratch myself. However, it's a standard code for generating using sieves right?

Comment: The python code ran successfully for all test cases. I am more comfortable in Java than in python. Since this question was pretty simple, I could map it easily. I hope I get to know what's the issue with Java so that I can not repeat anything that causes this error.

Comment: You need to do individual imports rather than a wildcard one

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I came across the constraint.txt file in the challenge which had the below rules for Java:

[image: Java Constraints]

So based on the point highlighted, I had used `import java.utils.*` wildcard import statement in my java code. Wildcard imports would constitute Blacklisted code, which was why I was getting the error. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: You need to do individual imports rather than a wildcard one