# Remove all Numbers that occur more than N times in the given Array

Tags: java, arrays, collections, java-stream

I am working on the level 1 of the Google FooBar Minion scheduling challenge:

> Write a function called `solution(data, n)` that takes in a list of less
> than `100` integers and a number `n`, and returns that same list but with
> all of the numbers that **occur more** than `n` times **removed** entirely.
>
> The
> returned list should **retain** the same **ordering** as the original list -
> you don't want to mix up those carefully-planned shift rotations!
>
> For
> instance, if data was `[5, 10, 15, 10, 7]` and `n` was `1`, `solution(data, n)` would return the list `[5, 15, 7]` because `10` occurs twice, and thus
> was removed from the list entirely.

This is my solution, but for some reason only 2 test cases are passing out of 10.

The strange thing is, the open test case `{1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5}`, `n = 1` is also failing, while in my local IDE it passes.

```
public static int[] solution(int[] data, int n) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
    if (data.length < 1) {
        return data;
    }
    
    if (n < 1) {
        return new int[0];
    }
    
    for (final int datum : data) {
        map.put(datum, map.getOrDefault(datum, 0) + 1);
    }
    
    List<Integer> t = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getValue() == 1)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .toList();
    
    int[] b = new int[t.size()];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
        b[i] = t.get(i);
    }
    
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> returns that same list but with all of the numbers that occur more
> than `n` times **removed** entirely.
>
> The returned list should retain the **same ordering**

According to the original problem statement, you need to discard only elements having the number of occurrences more than `n`, and nothing else.

There's **no requirement** that all elements in the resulting array should be distinct. It means you have to preserve all duplicated elements that will be encountered `n` or less than `n` times.

The approach of build building a histogram of frequencies (*counting the number of occurrences*) is correct, but you don't need `LinkedHashMap`.

This logic can be written like that using Java 8 method `merge()`:

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> countFrequencies(int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
    for (int next: arr) {
        frequencies.merge(next, 1, Integer::sum);
    }
    return frequencies;
}
```

Or with Stream API:

```
public static Map<Integer, Long> countFrequencies(int[] arr) {
    
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Function.identity(),
            Collectors.counting()));
}
```

To ensure the **order**, you just need to iterate over the given array, and filter out the element having frequency ***less*** or ***equal*** to `n`.

Also, there's no need to create an *intermediate list*, you can get the *resulting array* as a result of execution of the stream pipeline.

```
public static int[] solution(int[] data, int n) {
    
    Map<Integer, Long> frequencies = countFrequencies(data);
    
    return Arrays.stream(data)
        .filter(num -> frequencies.get(num) <= n)
        .toArray();
}
```

See the [*Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rTe)

Also make sure that you have all the **imports** at the top of the file you're submitting (*imports for the code given above are listed in the demo*).

And don't use `import java.util.*`, because of that your solution [*might not pass the tests*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61664771/17949945).

Comment: This fails too :(

Comment: @newLearner Which of the `8` tests are passed and which failed? You used the code from the demo without changes? It should not fail. Did you save the code after updating in the editor?

Comment: `2` out of `9` passed meaning `7` failed. Yes, I saved and copied the exact same code. It produces same result as my code did. Also, the test cases are hidden so I am not sure which failed.

Comment: @newLearner That's strange. Maybe you can add a screenshot of the editor to your answer.